# How to disable "show previous versions" in the Open File dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi

I've got a program that's using an IFileDialog (standard Windows dialog) to open files.  And on some computers, it all works as expected, but on others, the Open button has an arrow with a dropdown menu that adds a second option, "show previous versions".

A bit of research indicates that [this is an OS thing related to System Restore](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c74b9e69-4df6-437f-bdfc-b4f8237bdd9c/how-to-programmatically-enabledisable-previous-versions-of-files-on-windows7?forum=windowsbackup), and it can be disabled by turning off System Restore entirely.  But that would be [using global state to manage a local problem.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx)  Is there any way to simply configure the dialog to not show the dropdown menu?

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but why would you want to do this in the first place? If the user has enabled this feature, he will expect to find this dropdown (and won't be bothered by it, that's my point)

Comment: @Tibo: At the moment I'm just wondering what the options are.